# C++ : Creating an array with a size entered by the user

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering if we can make an array with a size specified by the user.

Ex:

```
int a;
cout<<"Enter desired size of the array";
cin>>a;
int array[a];
```

The above program won't work as array size has to be a **compile-time constant** but in my case, it is a variable.

Is it possible to make a variable into a constant and assign it as size of an array?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In C++, there are two types of storage: *stack*-based memory, and *heap*-based memory. The size of an object in stack-based memory must be static (i.e. not changing), and therefore **must be known at compile time**. That means you can do this:

```
int array[10]; // fine, size of array known to be 10 at compile time
```

but not this:

```
int size;
// set size at runtime
int array[size]; // error, what is the size of array?
```

Note there is a difference between a *constant* value and a value *known at compile time*, which means you can't even do this:

```
int i;
// set i at runtime
const int size = i;
int array[size]; // error, size not known at compile time
```

If you want a dynamically-sized object, you can access heap-based memory with some form of the `new` operator:

```
int size;
// set size at runtime
int* array = new int[size] // fine, size of array can be determined at runtime
```

However, this 'raw' usage of `new` is **not recommended** as you must use `delete` to recover the allocated memory.

```
delete[] array;
```

This is a pain, as you have to remember to `delete` everything you create with `new` (and only `delete` once). Fortunately, C++ has many data structures that do this for you (i.e. they use `new` and `delete` behind the scenes to dynamically change the size of the object).

`std::vector` is one example of these self-managing data structures, and is a direct replacement for an array. That means you can do this:

```
int size;
// set size at runtime
std::vector<int> vec(size); // fine, size of vector can be set at runtime
```

and don't have to worry about `new` or `delete`. It gets even better, because `std::vector` will *automatically* resize itself as you add more elements.

```
vec.push_back(0); // fine, std::vector will request more memory if needed
```

In summary: don't use arrays unless you know the size at compile time (in which case, don't use `new`), instead use `std::vector`.

Comment: ```int size;
// set size at runtime
int* array = new int[size]``` isn't working for me. I did exactly that, but it's a 2 d array of floats. Says value n must be a constant. My code: ```int n;
    cin >> n;
    float* matrixA = new float[n][n]; ``` when changing int n to const int n, i get the exact same message. Any ideas?

Comment: ah nvm figured it out. I had to make them single dimension arrays using that syntax, then iterate through it adding new float[n] to each of those

Comment: The answer is very clear but I don't agree with the last statement, there are plenty of cases in which you'll want to allocate an array on the heap using `new` and `delete` without the overhead that a `std::vector` introduces.

Answer (score 5):

Use `std::vector` (requires header `<vector>`):

```
int size;
cout<<"Enter desired size of the array";
cin >> size;
std::vector<int> array(size);
```

Comment: As I said , i am new to c++ . Could you provide a brief explanation pls thanks :)

Comment: You may look at one of these doc [www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) or [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: but isnt this creating a vector and not an array?

Comment: @MohitBhasi `vector` class is implemented as an array under the hood.

Comment: @Algo; Fortunately, that is totally irrelevant in this case.

Answer (score 4):

### Using dynamic allocation

[More on dynamic memory in C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int size;
    std::cout <<"Enter desired size of the array";
    std::cin >> size;
    int *array = new int[size];
}
```

As mentioned in the linked article above:

> In most cases, memory allocated dynamically is only needed during specific periods of time within a program; once it is no longer needed, it can be freed so that the memory becomes available again for other requests of dynamic memory. This is the purpose of operator delete.

When you're done with `array` you should delete it using the following syntax:

```
delete[] array;
```

### Using `std::vector`

[More on vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int size;
    std::cout <<"Enter desired size of the array";
    std::cin >> size;
    std::vector<int> array(size);
}
```

Comment: If you are going to show a beginner how to dynamically allocate an array it is only fair if you also show how to delete it again. Don't make it seem easier than it is.

Comment: That's what the link above is for

Comment: Sure, but why provide a self-contained example that demonstrates bad practice?

Comment: @Algo thx a lot ! Dont know anything abt vectors so the first option helped me understand a new concept

Comment: @Algo so i read the article and learnt a bit of extra info. But I dont get the point of using the delete[] . Does dynamic memory allocation allocate same space of memory every time when I use`new`

Comment: @MohitBhasi `new` will always allocate unused memory. The point is, if you use `new` and don't remember to also `delete` when you are done with the memory then that memory is lost. That is called a memory leak and is bad news. Managing dynamically allocated memory is hard and is the main reason why it is recommended to use objects that manage the memory for you like `std::vector`.

Comment: @ChrisDrew ok so for vectors , there is no question of a memory leak but when assigning memory using `new` it has to be deleted to prevent memory leak

Comment: @MohitBhasi the vector version is much simpler to use

Comment: In the general case, the `new` version is impossible to use correctly. Don't ever do that. I downvoted just for this.

Comment: @Algo: Yep. It's quite impossible to make a program developed that way correct with a remotely competitive investment in time.