# How Process With An String Array In C++

Tags: c++, arrays, process, cin

In One Of My Question , I Need To Get 'n' String And After I Get The Strings , I Should Process With Them:

```
{
int n=0;
cin>>n;
string user[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  cin>>user[n];
}
```

}

After I Get String How I Can Process With Them And Compare Them?

For Example If I Enter This Strings : "asdabdabmsd" and "ajksdasbgdjkabs" , How I Can Compare Specified Word In This Two String With Together?

Comment: `cin>>n;string user[n];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have the number of entries denoted by a constant, not a variable.

Comment: I need to compare second word of first string with fourth word in second string.
how i can write it in c++ ?

Comment: Nothing will be compared if you use invalid syntax.  Use `std::vector<std::string> user(n);`

Comment: I want To compare Them By turn them into char string and compare the words with their ASCIIs codes.
i  dont want to use any functions.

Comment: Do you understand what I am referring to?  You can't declare arrays using a variable like `n`.  Arrays must have their sizes already known.

Comment: In New Ver of c++ we can take the size of arrays as a variable.
We can give a desired value to array size.
{
int n=0;
cin>>n;
string user[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  cin>>user[n];
}

Comment: No, there is no "new version" of C++ that does this.  Where are you getting your information from?  If you want a dynamic array, the way you do it in C++ is to use `std::vector`

Comment: @Ali Could you please post complete code which you think not working properly? It will help to understand what you are trying to do. Also please edit your question to make it more clear and format your code properly.

Comment: Read This Topic To Understand me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625465/c-creating-an-array-with-a-size-entered-by-the-user

Comment: @Ali -- Did you read the answer that was given to you at that link?  It is the same thing I have been saying to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the length of two strings.After that use two loops for two strings and compare both strings character by character.

Comment: The Problems Is Here.
i dont Know The Size Of This Strings.
if i know i will turn them into a char array.

Comment: There is a function to get the length of string.Just use that and get the length. Use this.int n=strlen(str);

Answer (score 0):

Firstly , correct the way you are storing strings. It should be cin>>user[i]

```
{
int n=0;
cin>>n;
std::vector <std::string> user(n);
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  cin>>user[i];  // it should be 'i' not 'n'
}

}
```

Secondly, if you want to compare,  say second letter of first string with the fourth letter of third string, use `user[0][1] == user[2][3]`

Means to get the ith letter of jth string, use `user[j-1][i-1]`

Comment: `string user[n]` -- I guess you weren't reading the comments above.

Comment: I dont see any problem using string user[n] , I checked it and it is running fine.

Comment: It is not legal ANSI C++ syntax.  Your example fails to compile for compilers such as Visual Studio.

Comment: I tried it on ideone.com and it is running fine. Sorry, I didn't check for visual studio. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: You are using compiler extension called `Variable Length Arrays` (VLA).  It is not standard C++ syntax, and gives the false sense that the code is valid, when it isn't.

Comment: is this two dimension array is a char array? or string array?

Comment: In terms of strings it is a 2D array, in terms of characters, it is a 1D array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie , should I remove this answer ?

Comment: Just change the answer to use `std::vector<std::string> user(n)`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @PaulMcKenzie. I learnt something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of cin to get the input string, you need to use getline() (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) or else if the input string contains white space the remaining part of the input string will not be ignored.