# Is creating arrays with runtime bounds allowed in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, runtime, variable-declaration

According to 
[C++ : Creating an array with a size entered by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28625465/c-creating-an-array-with-a-size-entered-by-the-user)
creating arrays with runtime bounds is not allowed in c++.

But I get below code compiled without errors.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {


    int n;
    cin>>n;

    int a[n][n];
    a[n-1][n-1]=9;
    cout<<a[n-1][n-1]<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and it works fine too. check it here -> 
http://cpp.sh/6bies

Can someone help to solve this confusion?.

Comment: Some compilers (ie. gcc) accept Variable Length Arrays as language extension (they are allowed in C). However, this is invalid C++ according to standard. Try enabling warnings in your compiler, it should mention that.

Comment: If you want to create runtime bounds array, you should look at dynamic arrays.

Comment: The linked example also shows a warning in the "compilation" tab

Comment: FYI:  my error looks like: "error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array ‘a’ [-Werror=vla]"  my compiler flags include "-Werror=vla"   Consider using std::vector instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is creating arrays with runtime bounds allowed in c++?

Such arrays are ill-formed.

> But I get below code compiled without errors. ... and it works fine too.

The C++ standard does not disallow compilers from successfully compiling ill-formed programs. It is sufficient to show a diagnostic message. This allows compilers to extend the language.

If you take a look at the compiler output of your example, you'll find that the compiler did tell you about it, as is required by the C++ standard:

> ```
> 15:15: warning: array of array of runtime bound [-Wvla]
> ```

So, it appears that your compiler supports arrays of runtime bound - and even arrays of arrays of runtime bound - as a language extension.

Most compilers can be asked to refuse programs that are ill-formed according to C++ standard, if you so prefer.

---

It is standard compliant to create arrays of runtime bound *in dynamic storage*. The simplest way is to use `std::vector`.

Comment: I'd also like to point out the difference between dynamic memory allocation, which means a heap allocated object, versus a dynamic data structure, such as a vector (also heap allocated), which doesn't have a size constraint like an already dynamically allocated array.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using gcc, it has some extensions, one of them being support for variable length arrays (VLA) that is available in C99.